# Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception on exchangeId

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have sftp expression like this:

```
"sftp://" +
                hostName +
                ":22" +
                mainPath +
                subPath +
                "?username=" + username +
                "&password=" + password +
                fileSecondPrefix +
                "&autoCreate=false" +//AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200706.txt
                "&strictHostKeyChecking=no" +
                "&preferredAuthentications=publickey,password" +
                "&disconnect=true" +
                "&connectTimeout=50000" +
                "&timeout=50000" +
                "&noop=true" +
                "&maximumReconnectAttempts=2" +
                "&fastExistsCheck=true" +
                "&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=false" +
                "&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true" +
                "&localWorkDirectory=" + "/temp" +
                "&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true"
```

I have a route like this:

```
nException(Exception.class)
                .process(reconciliationExceptionProcessor)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "reconciliationExceptionProcessor")
                .handled(true)
//                .maximumRedeliveries(5).redeliveryDelay(10000L)
                .to(SEND_MAIL_FOR_FAILED)
                .end();

        from(DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE_START)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Camel route started")
                .routeId("reconciliationCamelRoute")
                .process(createFTPExpressionProcessor)
//                .to(PREPARE_MAIL_FOR_FAILEDS)//todo
                .to(GET_FILE_FROM_SFTP)//todo
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Camel route ended")
//                .end()
        ;

        from(GET_FILE_FROM_SFTP)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Getting the file from SFTP")
                .pollEnrich()
                .simple("${exchangeProperty.sftpExpression}")
                //.timeout(0)
                .to(SAVE_RECEIVED_IDS)
                .end();
```

When it cant connect or cant find file, it should go to exception and then should go to mail send route because:

```
nException(Exception.class)
                .process(reconciliationExceptionProcessor)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "reconciliationExceptionProcessor")
                .handled(true)
//                .maximumRedeliveries(5).redeliveryDelay(10000L)
                .to(SEND_MAIL_FOR_FAILED)
                .end();
```

But logs are like this:

```
DocumentReconciliationRoute ReconciliationExceptionProcessor Exception occurred:
Message : Cannot connect to sftp://xxx
[org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:146), org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.connectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:203), org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.recoverableConnectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:183), org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.prePollCheck(RemoteFileConsumer.java:59), org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:119), org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175), org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102), java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511), java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308), java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180), java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]
 , Cause Message: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
reconciliationExceptionProcessor appName=maf-integration-offline-services podName=maf-integration-offline-services-842-2bvfx
Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception on exchangeId: ID-maf-integration-offline-services-842-2bvfx-41923-1598693278891-0-787 using: [Pipeline[[Channel[DelegateSync[com.avivasa.maf.route.offline.reconciliation.processor.ReconciliationExceptionProcessor@445f6f73]], Channel[Log(DocumentReconciliationRoute)[reconciliationExceptionProcessor]], Channel[sendTo(direct://DocumentReconciliationRoute.sendMailForFailed)]]]]. The previous and the new exception will be logged in the following. appName=maf-integration-offline-services podName=maf-integration-offline-services-842-2bvfx
```

Before exception, it waited too long to throw exception. **Timeout=0** is true? If i do this, it goes next route and file becomes empty from exchange so it throws exception because it cant find file . which is good?

Answer (score 0):

I think it happen becouse you've got exception in inner route. I didnt find any solution for transit exception from child route to parent in camel. In documentatin
they recomended create an abstract parent rout builder and call `super.configure()` in children.
My solution

```
public abstract class BaseRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        onException(Exception.class).to("ExceptionRoute");
    }
}
```

ChildRoute

```
public class BaseEndpointRoute extends BaseRoute {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        super.configure();

        // your route config
    }
```